# Need for using $and

Tags: mongodb, nosql

In MongoDB, I have this following code:

```
db.products.find({name: "Postcard", status: "Available"})
```

But isn't that the same as using `$and`? If not, what is the difference?

Another example...

Where the status equals "Available" **and** *either* qty is less than (`$gt`) 100 *or* name starts with the characters "Po":

```
db.products.find( {status:"Available", $or:[{qty:{$gt:100 }},{item:/^Po/}]})
```

So seems as if there is no need of using `$and` in these two examples. So why or when would `$and` be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both your examples it is superfluous to use $and because using ',' to specify match conditions on several **different** fields accomplishes it just the same.

One instance when to use them is if you need to specify multiple conditions on the **same** field. Here is an example (straight from mongodb tutorial videos).

```
db.movieDetails.find({"$and": [{"metacritic": {"$ne": "null"}}, 
                                "metacritic": {"$exists": "true"}]})
```

The explanation provided was that the keys in a JSON document must be unique. So if the above query were to be specified without $and, only the last "metacritic" value would be apparently be used.

Mongodb documentation specifies another example listed with a similar explanation. Notice $or operator being specified twice.

```
db.inventory.find( {
    $and : [
        { $or : [ { price : 0.99 }, { price : 1.99 } ] },
        { $or : [ { sale : true }, { qty : { $lt : 20 } } ] }
    ]
} )
```